# Info: Display the current node name in the buffer-list or uniquify *info* buffers

Tags: mode-line, info, uniquify

Is there a way to get `info` to display the current node in any of `buffer-list/ibuffer/helm-buffers`, especially when there are multiple `info` buffers ? Ideally `uniquify` should be sufficient to distinguish amongst multiple info buffers, but currently I only see `*info*<n>` (n being a natural number). My `uniquify-buffer-name-style` is set to `post-forward-angle-brackets` if it makes any difference.

Since emacs makes it relatively hard to open multiple info buffers, I am assuming my scenario is not idiomatic. I would prefer for a way to get uniquify do the right thing automatically, though I would be happy to hack something if someone can point to me the right way.

**I want to identify individual info buffers when switching in the buffer-list, preferably in the same manner as uniquify does.**

EDIT: Previously, I was not seeing the node name in the modeline as well and phrased the question as such. But turned out a modeline customization was overwriting it. So Drew's answer `info+.el` only solves the previous iteration of this question caused by a misconfiguration on my part. I have now emphasized my actual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the buffer list displayed by `list-buffers` you can see the current node and Info file in the last column (named `File`). But if you want to add the current node name to the buffer name, then when visiting a new node just type the prefix arg `C-u` before a navigation command (e.g. `C-u f` where `f` is bound to `Info-follow-reference`, or `C-u RET` where `RET` is bound to `Info-follow-nearest-node`, etc.) and it will display a forked node with the name `*info-<node-name>*`.

Comment: Note that `ibuffer` does not display the node name in a similar way.

Comment: Using the prefix argument before navigation solves my issue. I can use any of `ibuffer\helm-buffer` to quickly switch to a relavent info file.

Answer (score 5):

If you use library [**Info+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/InfoPlus) ([`info+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/info%2b.el)) then the current node name is in the mode line by default.

In fact, breadcrumbs are shown in the mode line by default (and the breadcrumbs end in the current node name). This is controlled by option and command **`Info-breadcrumbs-in-mode-line-mode`**.

(You can alternatively or additionally show breadcrumbs in the header line - option `Info-breadcrumbs-in-header-flag`.)

As for opening multiple Info buffers: most often I use `M-n` to clone the current Info buffer and navigate to where I want the clone to go.

Comment: Ooh, `info-virtual-book` seems really handy. I can see myself making some cheatsheets. I will wait for a day before marking the question answered. Thanks for the package.

Comment: Yes, wait, as I expect others will have quite different answers for this question. Your question is mostly about naming and recognizing Info instances, I think, and there are surely multiple ways to answer that.